# Code-behind in a custom EditForm page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I've inherited a project that has a custom Edit form for a list. It's called `EditFormCustom.aspx`. The page was customized through SharePoint designer. A code-behind was added by doing the following:

- Add `<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="4part assembly name" %>`
- A custom class with the name that the page is inheriting, `public partial class {classname} : WebPartPage`
- Deploy assembly to the GAC

This all works. **I can step thru the code and everything is fine and dandy**. What I'm having an issue with is programmatically locating controls that were added to the page in the designer.

This all worked when it was originally built for MOSS. It has since been upgraded to 2010, but the page cannot find the controls.

In addition to not finding the controls that previously existed (such as `FormField`), I added my own ASP.NET Label control. `<asp:Label ID="lblFINDME" runat="server" />`. Then from the code-behind:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblFINDME = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)FindControlRecursive(this, "lblFINDME");
```

And the `FindControlRecursive` method:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
{
    if (Root.ID == Id)
        return Root;


    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
        if (FoundCtl != null)
            return FoundCtl;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is this not possible?

**Edit 1**

I am able to get a handle on some other controls, such as the master pages Placeholder controls.

**Edit 2**

I now added a sample label control within the `PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea` control in the top of the page. I was able to get a handle on this control! In fact, I had intellisense in SPD when writing this control too. The control that I'm not able to find are within the `PlaceHolderMain` content place holder.

**Edit 3**

Very interesting. Just found that the control I'm trying to find is within a DataFormWebPart. I've never work with one of these before.

**Edit 4**

I've accepted an answer as it is specific to the question I asked. However, my problem was unrelated. Apparently when the transform of your xslt takes longer than 1 second, a stack overflow exception occurs. Because of this exception, my controls were not actually added to the page. I removed ~100 or so controls, so I only had 4 of them, 1 of them being the control I was trying to get a handle on. Sure enough, with only 4 controls to transform, it works without issue. Now I need to find a workaround.

Comment: fwiw - this is a case-sensitive method.  Do you have the ID typed exactly as it appears in the page?

Comment: Yup. Everything worked previously before the upgrade.

Comment: What page event is the call to FindControlRecursive() in?

Comment: It was originally built with `OnLoadComplete`. I've since moved it to `OnInit`

Comment: See my Edit 2 above

Comment: Now that I found that this is within a DataFormWebPart, perhaps the `OnLoadComplete` method was appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the call to `FindControlRecursive()` in `CreateChildControls()` *after* the call to `base.CreateChildControls()` or in `OnLoad()`.  For details on the page life cycle, check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  You may also need to place a call to [EnsureChildControls()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.ensurechildcontrols.aspx) prior to calling your method.

Comment: This does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, I posted that right before I read your second edit.  It seems that you need to do slightly different logic in order to access controls in a content placeholder.  This should explain it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx.  Of particular importance is that controls in ContentPlaceHolders are not always available when the page is rendered as those areas are intended to be replaced with page content.

Comment: Did you see my 3rd edit? I found that the control I need is in a DataFormWebPart. I can get a handle on that web part, but need to access controls within it.

Comment: Unfortunately anything within the control will be specific to your exact implementation.  The control does provide a controls() collection but I suspect that you will need to use one of the other methods or properties to get the exact control you need : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart_properties.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I've accepted your answer as it answers my specific question. However, my issue was occurring because of other things. See my `Edit 4` for details.