# InfoPath Filtering

Tags: infopath, filter, xpath

I am working on a form for a SharePoint list called `Scheduling`, to be used for scheduling assets.  The problem I am looking at now involves filtering the options in a multiple-selection list.  I would like to be able to pull in data from the `Assets` list, and display it in the selection list only if that asset is not listed in another entry in the `Scheduling` list during the time-frame specified in the form.  Is there a way to go over these other entries en masse?  Right now I am pulling in the `Scheduling` list again as a REST data source so that I can get to all of the entries.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the question it seems you are developing an InfoPath form. If you can code then there is a feature where you can write code-behind (business logic) in C# or VB.Net that will pull in data from the Assets list, and display it in the selection list (I consider this as third list as per my understanding), only if that asset is not listed in another entry in the Scheduling list.

This article will help you in understanding how can add a code to your InfoPath form, if you are not already aware:

http://johanolivier.blogspot.in/2010/08/infopath-2010-development-part-1-add.html

Comment: This was actually my first instinct, but it appears that it is not possible to add custom code to a SharePoint List form, and I don't think that a form library fits the current project.

Comment: Hi Crash, if you are using custom SharePoint List Form then you may add code, ex: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22563/code-behind-in-a-custom-editform-page

Comment: You may also check this to add code to list form:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/6e7d8c9c-fdc9-462c-890a-1af8b1b629c4

Comment: I can't test this just yet, as the company may be forbidding me from using even sandboxed code, but hopefully I'll get them to let me do some work soon and I'll let you know.  Thanks for the help!